# OpenCv Python frame empty in mjpeg stream from webcam

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x, stream, mjpeg

I'm creating a program that displays 4 mjpg cameras in a grid, my problem is that sometimes it happens that a frame is empty and the stream freeze, I capture the error by checking the size of each frame, and if it is equal to 1 I continue the cycle, my problem is that I remain in the control loop, it seems that the stream flow is not able to obtain a valid frame, any suggestion?

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://85.90.40.19/mjpg/video.mjpg")
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture("http://85.90.40.19/mjpg/video.mjpg")
cap3 = cv2.VideoCapture("http://85.90.40.19/mjpg/video.mjpg")
cap4 = cv2.VideoCapture("http://85.90.40.19/mjpg/video.mjpg")



cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)

cv2.setWindowProperty('frame', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

while True:

    try:
         ret, frame = cap.read()
         ret2, frame2 = cap2.read()
         ret3, frame3 = cap2.read()
         ret4, frame4 = cap2.read()
     except:
         print("try catch")
         continue



     size = np.size(frame)
     size2 = np.size(frame2)
     size3 = np.size(frame3)
     size4 = np.size(frame4)


     if (size or size2 or size3 or size4) == 1:
        print("frame 0")
        continue

     # print("Dimensione" + str(size))

     rframe = cv2.resize(frame, (640,480))
     rframe2 = cv2.resize(frame2, (640,480))
     rframe3 = cv2.resize(frame3, (640,480))
     rframe4 = cv2.resize(frame4, (640,480))

     print(ret,ret2,ret3,ret4)


     vert1 = np.vstack((rframe,rframe2))
     vert2 = np.vstack((rframe3,rframe4))

     both = np.hstack((vert1,vert2))
     print(both.shape)
     # both.resize((1024, 768,3))

     cv2.imshow('frame', both)
     if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Comment: You call `cap2.read()` 3 times, is this intentional or just part of testing? i.e. cap3 and cap4 do not get used.

Comment: @MartinEvans my stupid mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could I suggest the following type of approach:

```
try:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
except:
    ret, frame = (-1, blackframe)

try:
    ret2, frame2 = cap2.read()
except:
    ret2, frame2 = (-1, blackframe)

try:
    ret3, frame3 = cap3.read()
except:
    ret3, frame3 = (-1, blackframe)

try:
    ret4, frame4 = cap4.read()
except:
    ret4, frame4 = (-1, blackframe)
```

Where `blackframe` is a suitable image that you have available for when a capture fails. This would allow the other frames to continue to be displayed.

The aim is to remove the `continue` statement which causes execution to return to the top without letting any of the other code execute.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and i report back

Comment: This solution seems to have resolved the problem, thank you very much, if someone need this i created the blackframe in this way:

blackframe = np.zeros((640, 480, 1), np.uint8)